# Javascript Order array by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I have an array with clients_id. This array is sort by delivery order.
This delivery order can change : I have a function (Framework7 based) with sortable list.
I need to sort the delivery list when it has been changed with the sortable list function.

1 - When the page is loaded I save Array in a hidden div.
client1,client2,client3,client4... (Sort by delivery order)

```
<div id="initialsort" style="display:none"></div>
```

The list :

```
<li>client1</li>
<li>client2</li>
<li>client3</li>
<li>client4</li>
```

2 - I have a function that detect the draged client in list to change the position

```
$$('li').on('sortable:sort',function(event){
alert("From " + event.detail.startIndex + " to " + event.detail.newIndex);
}
```

3 - Initial delivery Array (dynamic) :

```
client1 [0]
client2 [1]
client3 [2]
client4 [3]
```

For example, if user put the client 3 in first delivery position the Array should become :

```
client4 [0]
client1 [1]
client2 [2]
client3 [3]
```

I need to get and save the new array everytime the user change position of the list.
Hope somebody can Help !

Comment: I have added jQuery and jQuery-ui as I assume that's jQuery is the $ and `sortable:sort` is an event from jQuery-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per requirement i created a method. hope it will be helpful.

```
var clientNewPosIndex = 0;
var clientOldList = ["client1","client2","client3","client4"];
var clientName = "client4";
function clientNewPos(clientNewPosIndex,clientName,clientOldList){
      var clientNewList = clientOldList;
      var clientOldPosIndex= clientNewList.indexOf(clientName);
      if(clientOldPosIndex > -1){
            clientNewList.splice(clientOldPosIndex,1);
            clientNewList.splice( clientNewPosIndex, 0, clientName);
      }else{
            clientNewList.splice( clientNewPosIndex, 0, clientName);
      }
      return(clientNewList);
};
console.log(clientNewPos(clientNewPosIndex,clientName,clientOldList));
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Rana, your code works only if you drag to the first position. If you drag "client4" to second position it array like you put client4 to the first position. Any Idea ?

Comment: you can change the value of var clientNewPosIndex = 1; to change the position of client.

Comment: Works Fine. Thank you Gaurav Rana

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, basically you have to swap the items if you know the drag and drop position. **"For example, if user put the client 3 in first delivery position the Array should become"** from this I can propose the following solution. just a swap of array elements using position.

```
var arr = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]
var oldPos = 3
var newPos = 0
var tmp = arr[newPos]
arr[newPos] = arr[oldPos]
arr[oldPos] = tmp 
console.log("arr : ", arr)
```

output: [ 'c4', 'c2', 'c3', 'c1' ].

Answer (score 0):

This will help you, I hope.. @varatharajan there is some more you need to do with your code. I think you almost nearer.. but you understood the problem wrongly I think so..

```
var arr = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"];
var arrLength = arr.length();
var i = 0;
while(i < arrLength-1){
var temp = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[arrLength-1];
arr[arrLength-1] = temp;
i++;
}
console.log("arr : ", arr)
```